# Socket.io - Unable to send data from the Server side to client side using Socket.io in a Node/Express web app?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am trying Socket.io for the first time to basically create an application that can send data across both ways. I am able to **emit** data from the **client** and receive **on** the **server side**. But I am unable to do exactly the opposite. Please let me know if there are ways other than emit/on. The code on the Server side and client side are attached at the bottom.

Server Side

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('Connected');

socket.emit("event",'Some X JSON Object');

});
```

Client Side

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
 <script>

 var socket = io();
 socket.on("event", function(data) {
   console.log(data);
 });

</script>
```

Comment: https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example/issues/8 try with document.ready

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: In the console you mean? No, nothing related to socket.io

Comment: Have you checked the console in developer tools or are you expecting the client output to appear in your node console window where you run the app from?

Comment: I am expecting the output to be in my console window for the developer tool which is running the node.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your server side code to

`socket.emit("event",'Some X JSON Object');`

Look at [this tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) for help emitting and receiving events using socket.io.